# Vertically aligning span inside fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

I know, there are posts on this before, but I have looked over all of them and still can't seem to get this to work. Most of the related answers I've seen require you to specify the height of the containing div, which in my case is dynamic.

I have an fixed positioned div at the bottom of the window. I want to have a dismiss button just off the right side and always vertically aligned in the center of the div, no matter the height.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2zd3q0b/1/

```css
.bottombar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9990;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.bottombar p { /* Leave room for the dismiss button */
  margin: 0 1.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dismiss {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottombar">
  <p>This is some message inside of a div. I want to vertically center align the span. This is some message inside of a div. I want to vertically center align the span.<span class="dismiss">X</span></p>
</div><!--/.bottombar -->
```

In this case, it looks fine until the `bottombar` div takes up more than one line of text, then the span is no longer vertically centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `transform` that works well for unknown height container.

```
.dismiss {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  ...
}
```

```css
.bottombar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9990;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bottombar p {
  margin: 0 1.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dismiss {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottombar">
  <p>This is some message inside of a div. I want to vertically center align the span. This is some message inside of a div. I want to vertically center align the span. <span class="dismiss">X</span></p>
</div>
```

I also added `box-sizing` to the div in the code snippet so that gives you true 100% width including the borders, you might need to adjust the relevant spacing slightly.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If the inner div that you're centering is relative, you can include  `display: inline-block;` along with  `top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);` to center it

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2tk5t3c6/)

[image]

So I cleaned up some things and arrived with simple styling using `flexbox` (more info [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

```
.bottombar {
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9990;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* padding: 0.5em; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.bottombar>span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.bottombar .message{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.dismiss {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
<div class="bottombar">
    <span class='message'>
         This is some message inside of a div. I want to vertically center align the span.
    </span>
    <span class="dismiss">X</span>
</div>
```